# Is there a way to use RipGrep (or a similar tool) et all to search for a pattern, *but ignore results inside comments?*

Tags: command-line, vim, regex, search, grep

I'm a regular user of RipGrep `rg`, but one thing I can never figure out, and regularly find myself wanting, is to search *only* in lines that *aren't comments*.

Unfortunately,

1. It doesn't look like that's a first-class feature;
2. it looks like `rg`'s multi-expression support (`rg -e "a" -e "b"`) can only be a boolean OR, not a boolean AND — i.e. it adds additional results, doesn't remove previous ones;
3. and the simplest solution, using the shell (`rg 'a' | rg 'b'`) has enough downsides to feel like it's not a solution¹.

So, I'm on the hunt for a process or replacement that really makes this behaviour smooth. Does anybody have a favourite or idiomatic way to do this?

---

> 1. Although the pipe-thru-twice approach works to some extent, it fails in lots of ways that are important to me:
>
>    - Can't be used from within Vim that way, where I do most of my searching, with `:Ack` or the like;
>    - even at the command-line, loses context and settings: all sorts of features, such as printing line-numbers, colourizing results with ANSI codes, including context-lines, become very complex and fragile to re-enable/re-implement across two separate processes that aren't aware of eachother;
>    - and worst of all, using a second regex means you lose multi-filetype-awareness — i.e. grepping out solutions that don't start with `^\s*#` will catch most comments in your Ruby codebase, but won't do anything for the JavaScript or C parts. Do you chain even more invocations? Write a super-complicated multi-language comment-catching regex?

Comment: Do the comments expand multiple lines? Can you show some examples?

Comment: How do you know that a line is inside comments?

Comment: To `rg` and friends, text is text: comments, functions, etc. none of that means anything. If you don't think like that, then you should use a proper code indexing/searching tool instead.